# The stability of system using Lyapunov function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'd like to ask about the stability of system using Lyapunov function. Can we guarantee the stability of system when the Lyapunov function is bounded? Because as long as I know, we can guarantee the stability of system if the Lyapunov function is nonincreasing along solution of system.

Comment: This question is a bit too general to be answered precisely. For example, if the system is a queueing system with queues $(Q_1(t), \ldots, Q_N(t))$ and the Lyapunov function is $L(t) = ||Q(t)||^2$, then bounded $L(t)$ means bounded queues and hence a stable system.  So, it depends on what your "system" is, what "stable" means, and what you assume about your Lyapunov function.

Comment: Or, let $x(t)$ be a real-valued process and define Lyapunov function $L(t) = |\arctan(x(t))|$.  Then $0 \leq L(t) \leq \pi/2$ for all $t$, but this says nothing about the size of $x(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is relevant to your underlying question: 
Let $y=(y_1, \ldots, y_N)$ represent a vector in $\mathbb{R}^N$. Define the norm $||y|| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^N y_i^2}$.

Let $\mathcal{Y}$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$ (possibly being $\mathbb{R}^N$ itself).  Let $V(y)$ be a function from $\mathcal{Y}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  Suppose the function $V(y)$ has the following property that we shall call *property P*:

*Property P*: If $\{y[k]\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is an infinite sequence of vectors in $\mathcal{Y}$ that satisfies $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} ||y[k]||=\infty$,  then $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} V(y[k])=\infty$.

Let $x(t) = (x_1(t), \ldots, x_N(t))$ be a vector-valued function of time such that $x(t) \in \mathcal{Y}$ for all $t\geq 0$.

*Claim:*  If $V(y)$ has property P, and if there is a finite constant $C$ such that $V(x(t)) \leq C$ for all $t\geq 0$, then there is a finite constant $M$ such that $||x(t)||\leq M$ for all $t \geq 0$. In particular, if $V(x(t))$ is bounded for all $t\geq 0$, then $x(t)$ is bounded for all $t\geq 0$.

*Proof:*  Suppose there is no such $M$ (we will reach a contradiction).   Then for each positive integer $k$, there is a time $t_k\geq 0$ such that $||x(t_k)|| > k$.  It follows that $\{x(t_1), x(t_2), x(t_3), \ldots\}$ is an infinite sequence of vectors in $\mathcal{Y}$ such that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} ||x(t_k)||=\infty$.  Since $V(y)$ has property P, it follows that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} V(x(t_k)) = \infty$, which contradicts the fact that $V(x(t))\leq C$ for all $t \geq 0$.

---

Exercise 1:  Let $\mathcal{Y} = \mathbb{R}^N$. Show that the functions $V(y) = ||y||$, $L(y) = ||y||^2$, $H(y) = \sum_{i=1}^Ne^{|y_i|}$ all have property P.

Exercise 2:  Show that the function $V(y) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} e^{y_i}$ does *not* have property P when $\mathcal{Y} = \mathbb{R}^N$, but *does* have property P when $\mathcal{Y} = \mathbb{R}_+^N = \{(y_1, \ldots, y_N) \in \mathbb{R}^N | y_i \geq 0 \: \: \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, N\}\}$.

Exercise 3: Let $\mathcal{Y} = \mathbb{R}$.  Show that the function $V(y) = |\arctan(y)|$ does *not* have property P.

Exercise 4:  Let $\mathcal{Y} = \mathbb{R}$.  Show that the function $V(y)=0$ does *not* have property P.